# PNG Image: Pixelated frame

Tags: safari, png

I've got a strange image with a PNG file, where a pixelated frame appears when the image first loads. This is particularly prevalent in Safari, where it takes several seconds for the full, smooth, image to load.

Please visit this URL, change Split options to 'Redraw...' and click Split to see the frame I'm talking about: http://ezgif.com/split/01a0ed09bf.png

I was under the impression that PNGs don't support layers, so I don't know where this frame is coming from. I've tried several utilities to try to redraw the image, including imagemagick and pngquant, with no success.

How can I remove this frame from the image? Ideally this should be a command line tool as I have thousands of images to process.

Here's a link to the image:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-mqMIMqm_XHcG5wZk5pTUpvNWc/view?usp=sharing

[image: The image]

Comment: Unclear to me. The URL you provide converts to a GIF, the pixelation is due to lost palette transparency. This should have nothing to do with some "temporal" pixelation.

Comment: Perhaps the OP should look up Adam7 Interlacing. Or provide a link to the actual image, so we can tell if that is the case.

Comment: @Jongware That was it! Disabling interlacing in imagemagick with the -interlace none option fixed it. Post your comment as an answer (preferably with the imagemagick option I posted to make it helpful for others) and I'll accept it.

Comment: @leonbloy You're incorrect, the tool doesn't convert to GIF. You can see that for yourself by downloading the image on the page I linked to, and opening it in a text editor. Check bytes 1 to 3.

Comment: @IanNewson : uh? http://im.ezgif.com/tmp/01a0ed09bf-png-im/frame_000.gif

Comment: @leonbloy The image at the top: http://im.ezgif.com/tmp/63bf7325d7.png

Comment: Well, that's what I'm saying: the tool converts the PNG to GIF

Comment: @IanNewson: the *reason* you see the pixelation is explained in my answer (a combination of slow speed, large image, and an application that supports Adam7 loading). "How to remove" is another question -- probably best answered by the counter-question "why should you?"

Comment: @Jongware I removed it with imagemagick using the `-interlace none` option. As for why, because the client that's paying me says so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was barking up the wrong tree. The images were interlaced, and de-interlacing them improved but didn't completely resolve the issue. Turns out the actual issue I was seeing was a quirk of image rendering in webkit on OS X, which I ended up resolving using CSS:

```
img {
    image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
}
```

Comment: this completely fixed my issue!! this answer should be at the top!

Answer (score 2):

To quickly provide a preview *while a PNG is still loading*, the PNG Specification provides the option to save the image bits in Adam7 Interlaced format: http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#8Interlace

Instead of consecutively (top to bottom, left to right), every 8th pixel of every 8th row (starting top left) is stored. That information can be used to immediately draw an 8x8 rectangle in that color (and it is the correct color *for the top left pixel* only). Next, every 4th pixel is transmitted, so the receiving application can draw a 4x4 rectangle on top of the 8x8, then every 2nd pixel, and so on and so forth, until each pixel is transmitted exactly once.

The Adam7 pattern ensures that (1) each single pixel is only transmitted once, and (2) no new rectangle or pixel will overlap one that already has the correct color.

The counting diagram from the official specification shows it nicely:

```
1 6 4 6 2 6 4 6
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
3 6 4 6 3 6 4 6
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
```

It's up to the receiving application to decide what to do with the interlacing: some may decide to wait for the entire file to load anyway, decode in memory, and only then display the image, where others will use the loading time to show the preview.

If the loading application supports it, this will only be shortly visible on a relatively slow connection and/or with a very large PNG.

Comment: Nice answer, I appreciate the detail. It's worth stating that even though the  image was only 7k, and had been preloaded, Safari still decided to show the initial version of the image for 4 to 5 seconds.

Comment: @IanNewson: you're welcome. I agree that's ... suspiciously long. On the positive side, it gave you the opportunity of being introduced to Adam7 (which is, in the Age of Many MBits/sec, knowledge rapidly becoming obsolete).